# Tensorflow Keras Input layer does not add _keras_shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

According to the keras [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/), `Input` adds the `_keras_shape` attribute to the input tensor. However, as shown below, this is not the case.

```
import tensorflow as tf
s = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[2], dtype=tf.float32, name='s')
print(s._keras_shape)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'
```

Have I misunderstood something, or is this a bug I should report?

The lack of this attribute makes further Keras functions go haywire:

```
q_s = q(s)
model = Model(inputs=s, outputs=q_s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "/home/reuben/.virtualenvs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 253, in <listcomp>
  input_shapes=[x._keras_shape for x in self.inputs],
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'
```

I'm using tensorflow version '1.11.0-rc2'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input layer you get appears to be slightly different depending on whether you are importing from `keras` or whether you're importing it through `tensorflow`. The `keras` documentation you linked is based on importing layers from the `keras` library directly:

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input

s = Input(shape=[2], dtype=tf.float32, name='2')
s._shape_val # None
s._keras_shape # (None, 2)
```

However importing through tensorflow appears to save the shape in the tensorflow attribute `_shape_val` instead:

```
import tensorflow as tf
s = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[2], dtype=tf.float32, name='s')
s._shape_val # TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(2)])
s._keras_shape # Error
```

Your best bet is to just import the layer from `keras` directly. If you plan to continue using `tf.keras` instead of the main implementation of `keras`, you should refer to the [tf.keras docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras) instead of keras.io.

Comment: I think this points at a larger category of **issues caused when tensorflow keras and keras are intermingled**

Comment: @reubenjohn yep! make sure you don't get the docs mixed up! glad I can help :)

Comment: Hey that was really helpful, thanks. +1. Is there a list of these gotchas?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Input) does not mention `_keras_shape`.

"The added Keras attribute is: _keras_history: Last layer applied to the tensor. the entire layer graph is retrievable from that layer, recursively."

When you say "makes further Keras functions go haywire", what do you mean?

Comment: I've edited the question to elaborate on what I mean by 'go haywire', and realized that the cause is that I unintentionally used tensorflow.keras for defining the input and keras for defining the rest of the model. This is the source of my problems!